# UIPageViewController with calabash swiping

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, automation, calabash

I've been searching around for the solution to this problem and I'm new to calabash so I figured asking would be a good start.

I have a `UIPageViewController` and I want to test it with Calabash. I've tried using

```
Then I swipe right
```

which didn't work with `UIScrollView` or `PageView`. Then I found this which worked with `UIScrollView` but still nothing with `PageView`.

```
Then /^I swipe pageView to the (left|right|up|down)$/ do |direction|
    scrollViews = query("scrollView")
    scroll("scrollView index:0", direction)
    sleep(STEP_PAUSE) # optional
end

Then I swipe to the right
```

I can't figure out how to get this working for `UIPageViewController`. If anybody has any insight to this it would be great! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is this happening on the simulator or physical devices? As Rachel Gallen pointed out, there is a known Apple bug around swiping on the iOS Simulator.  This issue is being tracked here: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/issues/253

Comment: Calabash has to coordinate between many moving parts.  Xcode, instruments, ruby, cucumber, iOS, MacOS, and hardware versions are all required to accurately answer questions.  Please see this calabash-ios topic - http://goo.gl/yQi0bE - to see the details that you should include in your SO posts.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is an apple bug. this is the workaround

```
Then do right
    scroll("scrollView index:0", right)
    sleep(STEP_PAUSE)
end
```

however swiping only works now in portrait orientation in ios 7 (another bug)

Comment: The bug is only for the iOS Simulator.  This issue is being tracked here: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/issues/253

Comment: Is this actually a work around for the iOS Simulator swiping bug?  The code looks nearly identical to the code in the original post.  I upvoted you for mentioning the Apple bug and code formatting. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code :
scroll("tableView", :right)
or If you are not sure about view then just use : 
scroll("*", :right)

Or the easiest way to use is swipe : 
swipe "right"

At last give a try to :

You could try using performAction('drag',x1,x2,y1,y2,speed)

Where x1 is the horizontal percentage of the screen you want to start at,
x2 is the horizontal percentage of the screen you want to end at,
y1 is the vertical percentage of the screen you want to start at,
y2 is the vertical percentage of the screen you want to end at,
and speed is the speed of the drag.  The smaller the number, the faster the drag.

For your purposes, for example, swiping left to go to the next screen would be something like

performAction('drag',99,1,50,50,5)

If still you face the issue , comment below

Comment: Which command have you tried and what is the response you got